# Как правильно верстать макет, когда ширина экрана меньше ширины макета в пикселях?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Ширина макета 1920px.
Ширина монитора 1600px.
Вопрос: как правильно верстать такой макет и соблюсти все размеры и отступы?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1 - Уточните у заказчика, что он в курсе, что дизайнер сделал такой широкий макет. Предупредите, что без адаптивизации хорошо будет смотреться только на больших мониторах. Порой заказчики могут проглядеть ширину в макете дизайнера, не обратить внимания.

2 - Можете воспользоваться в дев тулс в хроме `toggle device toolbar` <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>. Там, в режиме `reponsive` можно вручную задать экрану ширину больше, чем монитор, при этом автоматически подберется зум. Работать будет даже пиксель перфект, однако будет достаточно мелко.

3 - Можете задать изначально для `body` в стилях фиксированную минимальную ширину равную 1920px. Появится горизонтальный скролл, и вы будете верстать пиксель в пиксель, не очень удобно конечно скроллить, однако не будет мелко, как в предыдущем варианте.

---

Причем, обратите внимание, что обратный зум не покажет вам реальной картины, и результат верстки может отличаться от настоящих больших экранов.

Обратный зум - это когда нажимаете <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> в хроме например, т.е 90%, 75% и.т.д.