# Как эмулировать большое разрешение экрана для адаптивной вёрстки?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Как эмулировать большое разрешение экрана для адаптивной вёрстки?

Comment: [Как правильно верстать макет, когда ширина экрана меньше ширины макета в пикселях?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655364/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82-1920px-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-1600px-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82/)

Comment: Причем, обратите внимание, что обратный зум не покажет вам реальной картины, и результат верстки может отличаться от настоящих больших экранов.

Comment: Обратный зум, т.е 90%, 75% и.т.д.?

Comment: Да, когда нажимаете ctrl- ctrl+ в хроме например

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для более точного определения разрешения, можно сделать следующим образом:

**В мозилле:**

**ctrl+shift+m**

Вверху можете вручную писать нужное разрешение 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В хроме:**

**Правой кнопкой мыши на сайте и выбираете посмотреть код**

Тоже самое, можете задавать свои параметры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто в там очень мелко всё, я вот думаю, может быть есть другие утилиты?

Comment: @ Quick Brown Fox   можете поискать сторонние сайты либо с масштабом поиграться

Comment: Спасибо, попробую) Про масштабирование. Выше сказали, что оно ложно отображает сайт)

Comment: @Quick Brown Fox я всегда проверяю так, как написал выше))